# Docker Swarm DNS fails for service name, but service virtual IP address and task IPs are resolved correctly. How to debug this?

Tags: docker-swarm

This question was flagged as not a good fit for StackOverflow as it is networking focused. Please let me know if there is a better place for it than here.

## TLDR;

In summary, from within a service container defined on the same stack as the service nginx:

```
nslookup nginx          # gives the virtual IP of the nginx service
nslookup tasks.nginx    # gives the correct IP of an nginx container (10.0.17.20)
ping 10.0.17.20         # this works
ping nginx              # doesn't work
curl http://10.0.17.20  # this works
curl http://nginx       # doesn't work
```

However, `curl http://tasks.nginx` does resolve. In context, the nodes are LXC containers. This beaviour does not occur using Digital Ocean VMs.

## The question

Within a Docker Swarm, I am findit that DNS resolution by servie name is failing from within containers. For example, with the following stack configuration:

```yml
version: "3.9"

networks:
  elk7:
    name: elk7
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "10.0.17.0/24"

services:
  setup:
    ...
    networks:
      - elk7

  es01: # placed on manger node 1
    ...
    networks:
      - elk7

  # ... es02/es03/etc

  nginx: # placed on manger node 2
    ...
    networks:
      - elk7
```

## ***Manager Node 1***

`docker network inspect elk7` shows that on this node a container for the `es01` service exists (I assume that I'm ***SUPPOSED*** to see only this node's containers?)

```
"9c1a019a5c83c466615819b5401bbb0e58c31f078a96f13ed4af3905c837d565": {
    "Name": "elk7_es01.1.meux9ctcmnfwdejiqmxftyeq8",
    "EndpointID": "e0b102827e93eb3d0439513778c308eeb1201cd1e8e252f1361692c2f9981cc5",
    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:11:11",
    "IPv4Address": "10.0.17.17/24",
    "IPv6Address": ""
},
```

And the IPAM section also seems useful to put here:

```
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "10.0.17.0/24",
            "Gateway": "10.0.17.1"
        }
    ]
},
```

## ***Manager Node 2***

Logging into the Nginx container (`docker container exec -it <container id> bash`), I am not able to contact the `es01` service via the service name, but I CAN contact it via the IP address:

```
root@2d6f42945a18:/# ping es01
PING es01 (10.0.17.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 2d6f42945a18 (10.0.17.20) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 2d6f42945a18 (10.0.17.20) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 2d6f42945a18 (10.0.17.20) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- es01 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4090ms
```

vs

```
root@2d6f42945a18:/# ping 10.0.17.17
PING 10.0.17.17 (10.0.17.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.17.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.17.17: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms

--- 10.0.17.17 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.128/0.174/0.220/0.046 ms
```

When I do an `nslookup` or `dig` I get an answer - so the service name `es01` does seem to resolve:

```
root@2d6f42945a18:/# nslookup es01
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   es01
Address: 10.0.17.16

============================================================

root@2d6f42945a18:/# dig es01

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Debian <<>> es01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17322
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;es01.              IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
es01.           600 IN  A   10.0.17.16

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 07:10:16 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

The `10.0.17.16` IP address is (I've just learned) the virual IP address associated with the es01 service: `docker service inspect elk7_es01` shows:

```
...
"Endpoint": {
    "Spec": {
        "Mode": "vip"
    },
    "VirtualIPs": [
        {
            "NetworkID": "rdtgyz97aahhsrlwz8u2mm8fy",
            "Addr": "10.0.17.16/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm unsure why I cannot contact a service task (i.e. container) via service name, when I ***CAN*** resolve the virtual IP of a service from within another service task (container).

What could be the issue? My Swarm nodes are all Ubuntu 20.04 LXC containers configured via Proxmox 7.0.11. The host IP addresses are all in the `10.8.66.0/24` range (not sure if this is important or not).

I do see that there are similar questions on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489435/docker-swarm-failing-to-resolve-dns-by-service-name-with-python-celery-workers-c), however the answer didn't help in my case.

Another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590866/wrong-ip-address-in-docker-swarm-service) mentions that you can look at the DNS resolution for service tasks explicitly via `nslookup tasks.es01`, and that gives the correct container IP addresses:

```
root@2d6f42945a18:/# nslookup tasks.es01
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   tasks.es01
Address: 10.0.17.17
```

Comment: `nslookup nginx          # gives the virtual IP of the nginx service` which is?

Comment: I've deleted the the LXC containers now, but the nginx virtual IP was something along the lines of `10.0.17.16` - just another IP address on the same subnet

Comment: And when you ping IP 10.0.17.16 does it work?

Comment: No it was doesn't